# Not able to solve Parse Error

Tags: php, html

I am writing php code in an html. Now I get a parse error which I am not able to trace!Could somebody help me fix it

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'">
  <img src="echo base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name'])">
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';
```

**Error**:-Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'uploads' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Second line, drop `echo` and replcae it with `'.` - then you'll need `.'` before `">` at the end on that line. Look at the syntax highlighting here on SO (or use a proper editor), and look at how you already concat strings together.

Comment: Look at this point `src="echo base_url`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'">
  <img src="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'">
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';
```

Comment: Why the down vote on this answer?

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step

```
$bu = base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']);
$d = date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created']));
echo '<a href="'.$bu.'"><img src="'.$bu.'"/><p>Uploaded On '.$d.'</p></a>';
```

to prevent typos and syntax errors

Note: added an missing `</a>`

Answer (score -1):

Make a var like this :

```
$linkToImg = base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']);
$uploadDate = date('j M Y',strtotime($file['created']));

echo "<a href='". $linkToImg ."'>";
echo "<img src='". $linkToImg ."'>";
echo "<p>Uploaded On ". $uploadDate ."</p>";
echo "</a>"; // Don't forget to close <a> tag
```